# angular ui-grid : how to use a variable parameter in the field property

Tags: angularjs, variables, angular-ui-grid

In my `ui-grid`, I need to bring the value given by the function of my `personModel`:

```
{field:'getValue("weight")',displayName:'Weight'},
```

But, I need to pass an other variable parameter to this function regarding to a date like this :

```
$scope.myDate=new Date();
{field:'getValue("weight",myDate)',displayName:'Weight'},
```

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would dynamically add this field to my data array after loading the data.

```
{field:'weightByDate', displayName:'Weight'},
```

and then

```
$scope.myDate=new Date();
$q.all([
    myDataLoaderFunction.$promise
])
    .then(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            data[0][i]['weightByDate'] = $scope.getValue('weight', myDate);
        }
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data[0];                
    }, function () {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = [];
    });
```

Perhaps that would work for you? (Note I have not run this code, there might be a syntax error in there somewhere.)